# Match a string with an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, vue.js

I have an array like this...

```
var array = ['aaa', 'bb', 'ccc', 'dddd', 'eee', 'fff'];
```

Also, I have a string like this:

```
5000aaa
```

or like this...

```
50bb
```

That string will vary, I need to put that matching part (`aaa`) into a variable and remove it from the existing string.

The final result should be like this:

```
var array = ['aaa', 'bb', 'ccc', 'dddd', 'eee', 'fff'];
var oldString = '5000aaa';
var matchedPart = 'aaa';
var newString = '5000';
```

Problem is the matching length is varied, And the string is dynamic (Getting from an input's value) However, every time the matching part only included in the end.

I can't figure out how to do this with pure Javascript or with ES2015 or VueJS. Can anyone guide me?

Comment: You can use [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for that.

Comment: could you have more than one item of the array in the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the replaced string and use a regular expression with optional patterns for searching.

```js
var array = ['aaa', 'bb', 'ccc', 'dddd', 'eee', 'fff'],
    replaced,
    string = '5000aaa',
    newString = string.replace(new RegExp(array.join('|')), s => (replaced = s, ''));

console.log(replaced);
console.log(newString);
```

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use a regular expression with an *alternation* and capture groups, like this:

```
var regex = new RegExp("(\\d+)(" + array.join("|") + ")");
```

`|` defines a series of alternatives, any of which is allowed to match. So for example:

```js
var array = ['aaa', 'bb', 'ccc', 'dddd', 'eee', 'fff'];
var regex = new RegExp("(\\d+)(" + array.join("|") + ")");
var str = "500bb";
var match = regex.exec(str);
console.log(match[1]); // 1st capture group: "500"
console.log(match[2]); // 2nd capture group: "bb"
```

**Note**: If the text in the array can have any characters that have special meaning in regular expressions (like `|` or `?` or `.`), you'll need to escape those when passing them to the `RegExp` constructor. There are various ways to do that in [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript). You'd apply it to the above like this:

```
var regex = new RegExp("(\\d+)(" + array.map(function(entry) {
    return rexEscape(entry);
}).join("|") + ")");
```

...where `rexEscape` is whatever escape function you end up defining and using.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a forEach loop to loop through the array, create a regex that matches only the array, and if it matches, return it.

```js
let array = ['aaa', 'bb', 'ccc', 'dddd', 'eee', 'fff'];
let oldString = "5000aaa";
let matchedPart;
let newString;
let re;

array.forEach((e) => {
  re = new RegExp(e, "g");
  if (oldString.match(re) != null) {
    matchedPart = oldString.match(re).join('');
    newString = oldString.replace(re, '');
  }
});

console.log(newString);
console.log(matchedPart);
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using simple Array and String prototypes. It can be done maybe more easier way using tons of regex but I personally avoid regex like its plague. Here is example:

```
function filterWord(oldString) {

  // Words that need to be left removed
  const arrayOfWords = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']

  // Filter though those words
  const filterWord = arrayOfWords.filter(function(word) {

    // Does string of aray include oldString?
    if (oldString.includes(word)) return word;
  });

  // If there was no match in filtering, 0 index will be undefined
  const matchedWord = filterWord[0] || false;

  // If there where no matchs, return false
  if (!matchedWord) return false;

  // Remove forbiden part from oldString with string.replace
  const newString = oldString.replace(new RegExp(matchedWord,"g"), "");

  return  {
    oldString: oldString,
    matchedPart: matchedWord,
    newString: newString
  }

}

console.log(filterWord('500aaa'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use regex to solve your problem.

```
 var array = ['aaa', 'bb', 'ccc', 'dddd', 'eee', 'fff'];
    var oldString = "5000aaa";
    var regexStr = oldString.match(/[a-z]+|[^a-z]+/g); 

    console.log({"oldString": oldString,
    "matchedPart": regexStr[1],
    "newString": regexStr[0]});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the patterns are simple strings always located at the end, then I don't think you need regular expressions for this.

I would create a function `splitFunction` which takes an array of patterns and return a function which takes a string and checks if it ends with one the patterns. It returns an array with the new string and the matched pattern.

By returning an array, you can then use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```js
const splitFunction = patterns => str => {
  const pattern = patterns.find(p => str.endsWith(p));
  return !pattern ? [] : [str.slice(0, -pattern.length), pattern];
};

const split = splitFunction(['aaa', 'bb', 'ccc', 'dddd', 'eee', 'fff']);

const [newString, match] = split('500aaa');

console.log(newString, match);
```